# Children should not watch me

Tags: riddle

I am four corners.
I both destroy and tantalize.
I intersect.
I describe what children shouldn't watch.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you are

> The letter 'X'

I am four corners

> The shape of the letter is four corners, meeting at a point

I both destroy and tantalize

> X can be a symbol for deletion, or a film rating later adopted by pornography

I intersect

> The shape of the letter, again

Children should not watch me

> Again refering to "X-rated" films

Comment: Congrats, KSmarts.  You got it.

Comment: How will I ever tell my son he can't watch *X-men* any more? ;)

Comment: @MichaelRize, stick to one thing, either the letter X or X-rated movies

Comment: I updated the riddle to make it more literal

Comment: @MichaelRize I prefer to make riddles very literal (e.g. the word "I" always used for the same thing, so "I sound like" if it's a homophone), but everyone has their own style - don't let yourself be pressured too much! :-)

Answer (score 5):

I am four corners.

> A TV set is generally square or rectangle which are shapes with four corners

I both destroy and tantalize.

> Watching TV is time killer at the same time entertaining

I intersect.

> Time spent watching TV means less time for socialising, so it intersects/cuts your relationship

Children should not watch me.

> Watching TV is bad for eyes and children should have more outdoor activities

Answer:

> I am a TV set